# How to burn MP3 files to a playable audio CD

Tags: windows-xp, audio, mp3, burning, compact-disc

I have six MP3 files I would like to put on a CD. They should be playable in all stereos so I guess I would need them in WAV format(?).

I have Windows XP. What is the easiest way to make my CD?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to do any conversion. You can use [CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/):

> Create Audio-CDs
>
> - **create Audio-CDs from mp3, wav, ogg, flac and wma files**
> - add single or multiple tracks from existing audio-CDs directly to your
>     new compilation without ripping tracks
>     before (add cda-files)
> - play audio-files with integrated audio player
> - gapless audio-CDs supported (disc-at-once-mode)
> - import M3U or WPL playlists
> - support for ReplayGain
> - import CUE sheets
> - create mixed-mode discs

CDBurnerXP is freeware (requires Microsoft .NET framework for versions 3.5 and above).

Answer (score 4):

> Burn audio CDs the easy way!
>
> **[Burrrn](http://www.burrrn.net/?page_id=4)** is a little tool for creating audio CDs with CD-Text from
>   various audio files. Supported formats
>   are: wav, **mp**3, mpc, ogg, aac, mp4,
>   ape, flac, ofr, wv, tta, m3u, pls and
>   fpl playlists and cue sheets. You can
>   also burn EAC’s noncompliant image +
>   cue sheets! Burrrn can read all types
>   of tags from all these formats
>   (including ape tags in mp3). Burrrn
>   uses cdrdao.exe for burning.

[image]

My favourite little audio burner, handles all important formats, 'understands' EAC's cue sheets (a HUGE plus in MY books) and easily throttles the speed (for better quality, lower writing speeds do indeed have a measurable effect on the quality of the signal burned into a CD-R)

*Burrrn is freeware (and easy to make "portable" with [Universal Extractor](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract)).*

if you're looking for a fully-fledged disk burning suite that does much more than just creating audio CDs from mp3, consider InfraRecorder:

**[InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/)** is a CD/DVD burning solution for Microsoft Windows. It offers a wide range of powerful features; all through an easy to use application interface and Windows Explorer integration.

[image]

Features:

Create custom data, audio and mixed-mode projects and record them to physical discs as well as disc images.

Supports recording to dual-layer DVDs.

Blank (erase) rewritable discs using four different methods.

Record disc images (ISO and BIN/CUE).

Fixate discs (write lead-out information to prevent further data from being added to the disc).

Scan the SCSI/IDE bus for devices and collect information about their capabilities.

Create disc copies, on the fly and using a temporary disc image.

Import session data from multi-session discs and add more sessions to them.

Display disc information.

Save audio and data tracks to files (.wav, .wma, .ogg, **.mp3** and .iso).

*InfraRecorder is open source freeware, a portable version is available.*

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why everyone suggests third-party software, as Windows XP can do this just fine on its own. Select the files you want on the CD, right-click them, select Send To, then your CD writer. The CD writing wizard will ask you whether you want a data or audio CD.

Answer (score 1):

You probably already have [iTunes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITunes) installed. If so, use that instead. It's free and does the job pretty painlessly.

Of course, if you don't already have it installed then it would be pointless to install it in which case one of the lighter-weight options in previous answer would be a better bet.

Comment: "You probably already have iTunes installed." ... a very daring assumption :)