# how to burn music onto a CD to play in my car?

Tags: windows, audio, burning, compact-disc, imgburn

I have some music files(.wav). I'd like to burn that onto a CD. I have downloaded the "imgburn" software. I am having trouble figuring out the next steps. Does anybody know the exact steps? There are just so many options to choose from. I want to burn those wav files onto an AUdio CD that can play in my car's CD player.Can I burn those Wav files on a simple CD_R or do I have to have a different kind of disk?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I love ImgBurn, and use it all the time - but it's not made for creating audio CDs, as I'm sure you've found.  Creating an image of an existing disk, sure; writing a billion copies of that image onto disks, yup; writing MP3s onto the disk **as** MP3s, no problem... but for writing audio CDs, you need some other program.

Answer (score 5):

**Burn audio CDs the easy way!**

> **[Burrrn](http://www.burrrn.net/?page_id=4)** is a little tool for creating audio CDs with CD-Text from
>   various audio files. Supported formats
>   are: **wav**, **mp**3, mpc, ogg, aac, mp4,
>   ape, flac, ofr, wv, tta, m3u, pls and
>   fpl playlists and cue sheets. You can
>   also burn EAC’s noncompliant image +
>   cue sheets! Burrrn can read all types
>   of tags from all these formats
>   (including ape tags in mp3). Burrrn
>   uses cdrdao.exe for burning.

[image]

My favourite little audio burner, handles all important formats, and easily throttles the speed (for better quality and compatibility with older CD players, lower writing speeds do indeed have a measurable effect on the quality of the signal burned into a CD-R).

*Burrrn is freeware (and easy to make "portable" with [Universal Extractor](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract)).*

Comment: +1. I love how all your answers have nice formatting and a picture.

Comment: Can we have a citation for "lower writing speeds do indeed have a measurable effect on the quality of the signal burned into a CD-R"?

Comment: you can indeed: http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/nov04/articles/qa1104-3.htm

Comment: The app is called Burrrn, it's showing a Johnny Cash album... yet for some reason it's an album without Ring of Fire. Opportunity for tasty wordplay, wasted. (Ring of Fire being the only Johnny Cash song I know.)

Comment: @Molly Ok fair enough - although that also says that "Most computer media these days is designed for very high-speed burning, usually over 24x. Such discs may not give reliable results when burned at low speeds." - So you'd want to find low-speed discs in order to burn at low speed reliably.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - true enough, for best results, it takes quite some experimenting with media and writing speeds. there is probably no general recommendation as there is also the difference between the various writers to be taken into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Whether your car CD player will play them depends on the player. The stock Bose stereo in my 12 year old car plays burned CDs, but I've had modern rental cars whose CD players would not play them. But it won't be too hard to burn a CD and find out.

A simple CD-R is fine.

I don't think Imgburn can create audio CDs. I think it can only create data CDs, unless it's burning from an .iso image (which you don't have). Try [CDBurnerXP](http://www.cdburnerxp.se), mentioned in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/85523/how-to-burn-mp3-files-to-a-playable-audio-cd).

John T.'s suggestion to use the built-in Windows software is also a good one.

Comment: +1 for CD Burner XP (I have added link to your answer), Whilst I feel that IMGburn has a larger feature set, it is more complicated and lacks some of the more basic features.

Answer (score 1):

The software I use is K3B on Ubuntu 9.10

You're likely to be using something different, but it's not a case of burning an *image*.

K3B calls it 'create an Audio CD'.

As for the media, it depends on your car CD player, but a modern CD player  should play an Audio CD you've made with a CD-R.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a CD-R.

To burn wav files, there is no additional software needed, right click the files and select **Copy to CD or Device**:

[image]

Windows Media Player will open and you can click the **copy** button if there is a CD in the drive.

In the context menu when you right-click the files, you can also use **Send To -> CD-RW Drive** (choose your CD burner). It will allow you to use the CD burning wizard.

Comment: Won't this burn them as files and not audio tracks?

Comment: No. The first method sends them to Windows Media Player, which will burn them as audio. The second option using the Wizard lets you choose between audio CD or data disc.

Answer (score 0):

Add the wav files to your library in Windows Media Player. Then Windows Media Player will be able to burn them to an audio CD. It will give you the right kind of CD (mastered, cda audio type) the first time, and there is no additional software required... this is available out of the box in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

As such there is no guarantee that even after burning, songs will be playable in car because it entirely depends on the car’s stereo system.  Make assure that it is capable to play mp3 or WMA files. In case it is not then you will have to burn in WAV format.

As you have asked about steps to burn song via imgburn, so here is the process:

- To burn music files you first need to create a CUE file.
- Now switch the right mode by clicking “write” option available at “mode manue.”
- Click the Create CUE file option. [you will find a ‘Create CD CUE file’ dialog box]
- Here click on brows option depicted as a folder icon at right upper corner. It will let you to select the songs files you want to burn on CD.
- Once you have done selection click OK and you will be prompted to save new CUE file.
- Now finally click on save button.